# "Could not load compiled classes for settings file" en Android Studio, al intentar ejecutar una aplicación

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy aprendiendo a usar AndroidStudio para crear aplicaciones móviles: descargué Android, ya tenía uno instalado pero lo borré hace 1 año, descargué todas las librerías, pero al correr una aplicación me aparece un error.

Les dejo el error que aparece, no creo que tenga que ver con el ejemplo que saqué de internet:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\lurias\AndroidStudioProjects\GetImeiActivity


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not load compiled classes for settings file 'C:\Users\lurias\AndroidStudioProjects\GetImeiActivity\settings.gradle' from cache. Expected class file C:\Users\lurias\.gradle\caches\jars-8\848aa088e669f13bc38c8f68b25b1cfe\settings.jar\settings_4fwzzq2b7ujajmw9dilylhnwl.class does not exist.
> settings_4fwzzq2b7ujajmw9dilylhnwl

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not load compiled classes for settings file 'C:\Users\lurias\AndroidStudioProjects\GetImeiActivity\settings.gradle' from cache. Expected class file C:\Users\lurias\.gradle\caches\jars-8\848aa088e669f13bc38c8f68b25b1cfe\settings.jar\settings_4fwzzq2b7ujajmw9dilylhnwl.class does not exist.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler$ClassesDirCompiledScript.loadClass(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:347)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.getScript(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:55)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:86)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptTarget.addConfiguration(DefaultScriptTarget.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:136)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:395)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:387)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:49)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
    at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.applySettingsScript(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.process(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:67)
    at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.process(SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.initialization.RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.process(RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.process(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findSettingsAndLoadIfAppropriate(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:120)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:58)
    at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.composite.CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.composite.ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.composite.CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(DefaultSettingsPreparer.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.doLoadBuild(BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer.java:59)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.run(BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:395)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:387)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
```

Desde ya les agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Como dato adicional: limpié el código, realicé un Rebuild, pero sigue igual.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer un

```
./gradlew --stop
```

y luego:

```
./gradlew clean --warning-mode=all
```